# One view vs. "composite" views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am in doubt how to construct my views and viewmodels... Lets see a (simplified) situation. I have a registration view with two variations: openid and strandard username/password. I see two ways how to

implement this:

**1.) First way: one view model and one view (some kind of Pseudocode):**

```
class RegisterViewModel:
- public string OpenId {get;set;}  // used only in openid registration
- public string Username {get;set;}  // used only in username/password registration
- public string Password {get;set;}  // used only in username/password registration
- public string PasswordConfirmation {get;set;}  // used only in username/password registration
- public string Email {get;set;} // used in both registrations
- public string FirstName {get;set;}  // used in both registrations
- public string LastName {get;set;}  // used in both registrations
- public RegistrationType Type {get;set;}  // used in both registrations
...
```

RegisterView.aspx (System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage):

```
...
  <h1>Account info</h1>
  <% if (Model.Type  == Registration.Type.OpenId) { %>
     <%= Html.TextBox("OpenId") %>
  <% } else { %>
     <%= Html.TextBox("Username") %>
     <%= Html.TextBox("Password") %>
     <%= Html.TextBox("PasswordConfirmation") %>
   <% } %>
  <%= Html.TextBox("Email") %>

  <h1>Personal info</h1>
  <%= Html.TextBox("FirstName") %>
  <%= Html.TextBox("LastName") %>
..
```

**2.) Second way: several view models and several views (user controls):**

```
abstract class RegisterViewModel:
- public string Email {get;set;}
- public string FirstName {get;set;}
- public string LastName {get;set;}

class OpenIdRegisterViewModel:
- public string OpenId {get;set;}

class UsernameRegisterViewModel:
- public string Username {get;set;}
- public string Password {get;set;}
- public string PasswordConfirmation {get;set;}
```

UserControl.ascx:

```
...
  <h1>Personal info</h1>
  <%= Html.TextBox("FirstName")
  <%= Html.TextBox("LastName")
...
```

OpenIdRegisterView.aspx (System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage):

```
...
  <h1>Account info</h1>
  <%= Html.TextBox("OpenId") %>
  <%= Html.TextBox("Email") %>

  <% Html.RenderPartial("UserControl") %>
..
```

UsernameRegisterView.aspx (System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage):

```
...
  <h1>Account info</h1>
  <%= Html.TextBox("Username") %>
  <%= Html.TextBox("Password") %>
  <%= Html.TextBox("PasswordConfirmation") %>
  <%= Html.TextBox("Email") %>

  <% Html.RenderPartial("UserControl") %>
...
```

---

I think that the first way is  not so OO, but it is easiery to align the view, and the second way is more oo, but it is hard to align elements - that is the reason why I didn't put email into the user control, because I want to have email near account info.

What option would you choose and why? Maybe some 3rd option? Where is the limit between these two options (when you choose first, when second)...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the second option:

- I can us the ascx on other views
- If I
  use Ajax I can have one ascx loaded
  asynchronously if javascript is
  enabled or load the full page if not.
  That makes it easier to implement
  both: an Ajax and non-Ajax version

I would only pass the required Model into ascx:

> 

I am not shure if I would realy put the common fields on the main view. It would be better to just be able to put the ascx on some other view and have all the fields you need.

Most of us come from WebForm - world where ascx are very powerfull. It was the first thing I looked at when evaluating MVC. Well there was not much to see.

But even in this very limited form they are usefull.

Comment: I have used this option because i will use control also on another views (edit user)...

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the **first option** because your situation is not complex enough to switch to the second option. In the case of more complex situations (for example the registration logic is completely different for different categories of users) I would prefer the second option. And I think you will need to make more efforts to test the second solution properly (as you said: *several view models and several views / user controls*).